# Associating a date range with a Drupal Taxonomy

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, taxonomy-terms

I am building a community site based on work locations and people who worked there over a period of time.
I have a taxonomy of 'locations' with 4000+ terms and a membership of 3000+ users. Each user could have worked at an unlimited number of locations over a period of many years (Mid 1950s to date).
I am stuck on how to refine attache a date range value to each users work at a location.
My intention is to programatically build relationships between users who worked at a location at any one time. e.g. 
1 - User BOB worked at location SHOP between 1999 and 2004. 
2 - User SUE worked at Location SHOP between 2001 and 2008 - These users have a relationship both with the location and with each other. 
3 - User JIM also worked at Location SHOP between 1975 and 1997 and therefore has no relationship other that with the location.
I suspect I need to know how best to add a date range to each Users relationship with the Location and how to compare these relationships with each other.
Any ideas or guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: You can make the relation via custom sql query

Answer (score 0):

Another option on D7 (sorry don't know about D8) would be to use a module like field collections.

This would allow you to have a field collection that contains a date & taxonomy term for your location.

If you add field_collection to your user you could allow it to have an unlimited number of values.